# AppArmor and ModSecurity gives me Apache2 fail

Tags: server, apache2, apparmor

I'v made a profile for `Apache2` with `AppArmor`, so after that I'v put it in complain mode but today I changed to enforce mode using `aa-enforce apache2` which gave me a problem while restarting `Apache2`.

```
*The apache2 configtest failed.

apache2: Syntax error on line 138 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf: Could not open config directory /etc/modsecurity: Permission denied.
```

So I went to see if I missed something while generating profile, since there is an error related to modsecurity - `/etc/modsecurity: Permission denied`

Here is what I have inside my file `usr.sbin.apache2`

```
  /etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf r,
  /etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.load r,
  /etc/apache2/mods-available/setenvif.conf r,

  /etc/modsecurity/* r,
  /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf r,
```

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says it cannot open *the directory* `/etc/modsecurity`; you may try to add explicit filesystem and/or AppArmor permissions for the directory itself, not only for the files inside.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by removing `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2` and then running `aa-genprof /usr/sbin/apache2` while restarting apache.